# Boundary of spectrum and norm of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

$H$ is a separable Hilbert space . $A:H\rightarrow H$ is a linear symmetric compact operator. Assume 
$$
\sigma(A) \le C
$$
Whether we have 
$$
||A|| \le C       ~~~~?
$$

What I think: first $H$ has a countable orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, assume they are $\{u_i\}$ . Then 
$$
||Au_i||=\frac{||Au_i||}{||u_i||}\le C
$$
Assume $\forall v\in H,~v=v^iu_i $, sum over $i$. Then 
$$
\sup_{||v||=1}||Av||=\sup_{||v||=1}||v^iA(u_i)||\le \sum_{i=1}^\infty Cv^i
$$
But I don't know how to show 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty v^i =1
$$
And I think it is not right .

Comment: I don't see the implication  in general, but if $A$ is a self-adjoint linear operator, then there exists an element of $\sigma(A)$ that achieves the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is selfadjoint, then

$\max\{| \lambda|: \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}=||A||$.

Your "implication" $\sigma(A) \le C$, then $||A|| \le C$ is not true in general !

Example: $A=diag(-1,-1)$, then $\sigma(A) \le -1$, but $||A||=1$

Comment: I think your self-adjoint is same with symmetric. Where I can find the prove ? Thanks.